# Golang Hot Folder file modification

Tags: string, go

I have the below program. It basically looks at a folder and checks for any new files. If it finds a new file, it makes a modification to the file. However, the way this is being done is actually inefficient and has a flaw. It copies the original content of the file into memory, makes the modificaiton, deletes the original file and then saves a new file with the content that was in memory. In reality, if anything goes wrong (which can happen), you lose the data once the file has been deleted. Ideally, I could make the modification in the file directly without deleting the original and thus needing to save a new one. As can be seen from the code, the modication is very small. I'm unfamiliar with how to do this in GO.

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"       
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "bytes"
    "strings"
)

const dir = "dir00003"

func main() {

fmt.Println("Running...")

//Go into a loop forever
for {

    //Wait 60 seconds before taking any action. 
    time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)
    //Read all of the file data for all files in the directory: 
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dir)
    if err != nil {fmt.Println("Failed to read transfer folder. There must be a folder named `dir00003`!"); continue}

    for _, v := range files {

        //if this is an index file, skip over it as we don't care: 
        if strings.Contains(v.Name(), "pmi") {continue}

        //if the file was created within the last 2 minutes, we should check if we need to modify it
        if time.Now().Sub(v.ModTime()) < (time.Minute * 2) {

            //open the file 
            f, err := os.Open(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", dir, v.Name()))
            if err != nil {fmt.Printf("\tCouldn't open file: %s\n", v.Name()); continue}

            defer f.Close()
            //read all of the bytes of the file
            bs, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
            if err != nil {fmt.Printf("\tCouldn't read bytes from %s\n", v.Name()); continue}

            //see if the <program_parameters/> tag is in the file
            b := bytes.Contains(bs, []byte("<program_parameters/>"))

            //if the tag is in the file, we should replace it, otherwise we move on to the next file
            if b {
                //replace the tag with nothing. Only look for the first instance and then abort the process of replacing.
                rbs := bytes.Replace(bs, []byte("<program_parameters/>"), []byte(""), 1)
                //close the file so we can delete it. 
                f.Close()
                //delete the exisint file. 
                os.Remove(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", dir, v.Name()))

                //create a new file with the same original name:
                nf, err := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", dir, v.Name()))
                if err != nil {fmt.Printf("\tFailed to create new file for %s\n", v.Name()); continue}

                //write all of the bytes that we have in memory to our new file. 
                _, err = nf.Write(rbs)
                if err != nil {fmt.Println("Failed to write to new file %s\n", v.Name()); continue}
                //close our new file
                nf.Close()

                fmt.Printf("Modified new file: %s", v.Name())

            } else {
                continue
            }

        }

    

    }

    fmt.Printf("\nDone with round\n")

}

fmt.Println("PROGRAM STOPPED RUNNING!!")

return 
}
```

EDIT:
Below is an updated version of the code that I made based on Abhijay Kumar answer. His original answer did not actually remove the text desired but the below code does. It is better than the original as it doesn't need to delete the file and is simply overwriting it. However, I was looking for an answer that would do an in file edit much like he was trying to do with the f.Seek function.

```
  // Open the file
f, err := os.OpenFile(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", dir, v.Name()), os.O_RDWR, 0644)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Couldn't open file: %s\n", v.Name())
    continue
}

defer f.Close()

// Create a buffer to read the contents of the file
var buffer bytes.Buffer
_, err = buffer.ReadFrom(f)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Couldn't read bytes from %s\n", v.Name())
    continue
}

if strings.Contains(buffer.String(), "<program_parameters/>") {
    
    rbs := bytes.Replace(buffer.Bytes(), []byte("<program_parameters/>"), []byte(""), 1)

    err = ioutil.WriteFile(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s",dir, v.Name()), rbs, 0660)
    if err != nil {fmt.Printf("Failed to WriteFile: %v", err.Error()); continue}                    

    fmt.Printf("Modified file in place: %s\n", v.Name())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify a file directly without copying the original content into memory or creating a new file. `os.File`, `os.Seek` and `os.WriteAt` functions can be used to seek the position in the file where modifications are needed. Below is a more efficient example that makes the modifications directly in the file:

```
// Open the file
f, err := os.OpenFile(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", dir, v.Name()), os.O_RDWR, 0644)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Couldn't open file: %s\n", v.Name())
    continue
}

defer f.Close()

// Create a buffer to read the contents of the file
var buffer bytes.Buffer
_, err = buffer.ReadFrom(f)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Couldn't read bytes from %s\n", v.Name())
    continue
}

if strings.Contains(buffer.String(), "<program_parameters/>") {
    // Find the position of the tag in the buffer
    index := strings.Index(buffer.String(), "<program_parameters/>")

    // Seek to the position in the file where the modification should be made
    _, err := f.Seek(int64(index), 0)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Couldn't seek to the position in %s\n", v.Name())
        continue
    }

    // Write the modified content directly to the file
    _, err = f.WriteAt([]byte(""), int64(index))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Couldn't write to %s\n", v.Name())
        continue
    }

    fmt.Printf("Modified file in place: %s\n", v.Name())
}
```

In this approach, we open the file with `os.OpenFile` using `os.O_RDWR` to allow both reading and writing. We then read the file content into a buffer, check for the presence of `<program_parameters/>`, seek to the correct position, and write the modified content directly to the file using `WriteAt`.

Comment: I believe this approach is correct. However, in practice it appears to not work. This example seeks and then writes a byte but is not actually writing anything []byte(""). Thus it does not remove the <program_parameters/> tag. This is why I loaded the entire text into memory because the replace function does the seeking and replacing for me. Replacing your code with this line instead:  ```_, err = f.WriteAt([]byte("                    
 "), int64(index))``` does work but is a bit annoying as there should be a proper way to remove the text from the file.